# Is there any memory usage difference between anonymous functions and traditional functions in Javascript? if so, how?

Tags: javascript, closures, anonymous-function

Is there any memory usage difference between anonymous functions and normal functions in Javascript ?

If so, how? Can you explain it?

Comment: If you mean anonymous vs named functions I don't think it makes a difference in performance to recommend one over the other. You could try doing a simple jsPerf test

Answer (score 5):

If by "normal functions" you mean functions declared as `function a(){` at the root level of your script, that is functions attached to the window object, yes there are differences :

- functions attached to the window object aren't garbaged while anonymous functions can be garbaged as soon as you don't use them anymore.
- they *might* slow the access to other variables of the window object (attaching the function at the root level is sometimes qualified of ["cluttering global namespace"](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#namespace) but the reason to avoid it is mainly to have a cleaner code and avoid name collisions).
- anonymous functions are [closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) : they keep a pointer to their enclosing scope, which enables the use of the variables defined in this scope. A side effect is that this scope cannot be garbaged before the function so the function can be heavier than you think and than a "normal function" (you can add an empty scope to enclose the anonymous declaration and prevent this effect if you don't need the variables of the scope but as I don't know if javascript engines can yet optimize away part of the enclosing scope I suggest you don't do it if you don't detect circular references).

But those differences are usually minor, you normally don't have to pay attention to that. In most of your pages your anonymous functions wouldn't be garbaged anyway as you don't remove the event handler (the first root cause of anonymous functions usually).

Globally (*premature optimization is the root etc.*) I recommend you favor readability as long as you don't have garbaging problems. Javascript engines and their GC change a lot, so your efforts could be useless.

Google has [an interesting notice about closure and memory](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml#Closures).

Comment: Not trying to invalidate your answer, but a reference to your statements would be nice :) (spec / test)

Comment: I added one. I'll add others if they come to my memory.

Comment: in first point i understood, anonymous functions can be garbaged as soon as we don't use them.But in third point you are saying anonymous functions cannot be garbaged before them.....can u explain it some more in detail?

Comment: I detailed a little, trying to be clearer. But I suggest you follow the links I give at the end to have a perfect view of the topic.